# Update ADF Linked Service configuration by API

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have requirement to update a ADF linked service configuration by API(or any other way through code, except using UI). I need to add 'init scripts' in the job cluster configuration of a linked service.

I got some Microsoft documentation on this, but it is only for creating a linked service, not for editing it.

Please let me know if you have any leads on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can update ADF linked Service configuration by API.

*Sample Request*

```
PUT https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/12345678-1234-1234-1234-12345678abc/resourceGroups/exampleResourceGroup/providers/Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/exampleFactoryName/linkedservices/exampleLinkedService?api-version=2018-06-01
```

*Request body*

```
{
  "properties": {
    "type": "AzureStorage",
    "typeProperties": {
      "connectionString": {
        "type": "SecureString",
        "value": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=examplestorageaccount;AccountKey=<storage key>"
      }
    },
    "description": "Example description"
  }
}
```

In this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/datafactory/linked-services/create-or-update#linkedservices_update) Sample Request and Request body are given.

For example, If you want to update AzureBlobStorage LinkedService, You can update configurations given [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/datafactory/linked-services/create-or-update#azureblobstoragelinkedservice)

Answer (score 0):

We use a PowerShell module [azure.datafactory.tools](https://github.com/SQLPlayer/azure.datafactory.tools) for deployments of ADF components.

It can replace a Linked Service with a new definition. Furthermore, you can test the deployed Linked Service with the module.